# Nest JS Authentication TypeORM

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs, typeorm

I am trying to follow the setup from the NEST JS documentation and implemented my own database, but I am having issues with this query.

I am fairly new to typescript, what am I missing here?

from users.service.ts

```
async findOneByEmail(emailAddress: string): Promise<User | undefined> {
    return this.usersRepository.find({ where: { email: emailAddress } });
}
```

from user.entity.ts

```
import { Column, Entity, PrimaryGeneratedColumn } from 'typeorm';

@Entity()
export class User {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

    @Column()
    firstName: string;

    @Column()
    lastName: string;

    @Column()
    email: string;

    @Column()
    password?: string;

    @Column()
    salt?: string;

    @Column()
    isActive: boolean;
}
```

from auth.service.ts

```
async validateUser(email: string, password: string): Promise<User> {
    const user = await this.usersService.findOneByEmail(email);

    if (user && user.password === password) {
        const { password, salt, ...rest } = user;
        return rest;
    }

    return null;
}
```

Edited:
forgot to share the issue

```
Type 'User[]' is missing the following properties from type 'User': id, firstName, lastName, email, and 6 more.ts(2740)
```

Comment: What happens if you try findOne instead of find? usersRepository.findOne

Comment: it works on .findOne(), still new to typescript, and I should've read the issue properly :)

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out, I just need to re-read the problem! From my understanding, `.find()` returns an array and I was only expecting one return.

```
async findOneByEmail(emailAddress: string): Promise<User | undefined> {
    return this.usersRepository.findOneOrFail({
        where: { email: emailAddress },
    });
}
```

Comment: i would suggest you to use findOne instead of findOneOrFail, since it will crash the app in the moment it does not find any entry

Comment: As @ardritkrasniqi suggested, you may wrap the code that may generate an error with `try-catch` and throw an error inside the catch block which prevents the app from being crashed if no entry is found.

Answer (score 0):

```
async findOneByEmail(emailAddress: string): Promise<User > {
return this.usersRepository.findOneOrFail({
    where: { email: emailAddress },
});
}
```

typeorm can handle error you should handle  error in another layer like usecase